# How to generate SQL from a user's visual interaction?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I am planning a C# SQL Query Builder application.  Basically, users should be able to generate SQL code by using a visual, form-based, user-friendly wizard.  All the user has to do is select which fields s/he would like, as well as impose some conditions.

I have looked into a number of applications which accomplish something similar, however none of them seem to explain exactly **how** the SQL code is generated.

What approaches could be taken to convert the user's interactions with the application, to SQL code?

**EDIT:** Just to add some more details. The application could be used with any SQL Server database.

Comment: All SQL code builders I have seen were built like `string query = "SELECT "; foreach (var c in columns) { query.Add(c + ", "); } ...`. It can be done better, but I believe that it is the simplest and fastest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on *what* can your user do .
As the question is *very* general, the answer that I can give is:

Try to map your flow-chart to `LINQ-SQL` code, and the real SQL translation leave to `LINQ` driver. In this way you get

- scallability : can map to different SQL databases, to XML, to ...X
- reliability

Answer (score 1):

The genesis of contemporary visual query builders is [query-by-example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example)

Answer (score 0):

Expreesion Trees can help you if you need a custom solution. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

I think you could use any ORM to do that, you will need to translate your objects from UI to queries (linq, strings or whatever) with a custom engine.